# Fade In Background Without Certain Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a background image that I want to fade in and out.  So I use jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut for my wrapper div.  The problem is the wrapper div has my sidebar and navigation as position:absolute within the wrapper div, and they also fade in and out with the background image of the wrapper div.  Here is the code (which doesn't work.  It fades everything.):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="navigation"></div>
        <div class="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
}

.navigation {
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    left:200px;
}

.sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 200px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var wrapper = $(".wrapper").not(".sidebar, .navigation");
wrapper.fadeOut(2000, function () {
    wrapper.css("background", "url(" + image + ")");
    wrapper.fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Comment: have you tried adding a `<div>` just for the background image and position it absolutely underneath with 100% width and height and fade that div ?

Comment: If they [sidebar and navigation] are positioned absolutely, why do you make yourself a trouble placing them inside `wrapper`? Make a `container` that has `wrapper` inside and `main` as child controls. And fade `wrapper` independently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest instead of doing the wrapper itself, do a wrapper-overlay that contains the image.

```
<div class="wrapper-overlay"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="navigation"></div>
        <div class="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper-overylay {
position: absolute;
z-index: above wrapper, below sidebar and nav;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Or you could just move the sidebar and nav outside of the wrapper (this might be the better approach), and sit on top of it all together.